# react-native: components with zIndex in flatlist does not seem to work

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-stylesheet

The main render:

```
  render() {
    return (

    <View>
      <FlatList
      ListEmptyComponent={() => <DialogBox type="internet" />}
      ...
    </View>
     );
```

`<DialogBox type="internet" />` container styled via absolute position:

```
export const dialogBox = EStyleSheet.create({
   container : {
       position: 'absolute',
       justifyContent: 'center',
       alignItems: 'center',
       top: 0,
       left: 0,
       right: 0,
       bottom: 0,
       zIndex:10000

   },
   ....
```

and DialogBox:

```
  <View style={dialogBox.container}>
       <View style={dialogBox.box}>
       ...
```

If I remove `absolute` form container, It shows. 
But I want show it in middle of screen (not middle of flatlist).

But why dosen't work zIndex in absolute?

I try change the code to this:

```
    <View style={{position: 'absolute',zIndex:1}}>
      <FlatList
      style={{position: 'absolute',zIndex:2}}
```

or this:

```
    <View style={{position: 'relative'}}>
      <FlatList
      style={{position: 'relative'}}
```

But it's not work

Answer (score 3):

You can add `CellRendererComponent` to the `FlatList`, even simply adding this seems to work:

```
CellRendererComponent={({children}) => children}
```

Note: Android will crash unless you add:

```
removeClippedSubviews={false}
```

Comment: Hi, where exactly do I add this?

Comment: These are props of RN's `FlatList`

Answer (score -1):

**zIndex** working not only for **absolute** position.

```
touchableCard: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    zIndex: 200,
    ...
  },

  emptyNotesInfo: {
    textAlign: "center",
    zIndex: 100,
    ...
  },
```

Try this:

```
   <View>
      <FlatList style={{flex: 1}}
        renderItem={ data => <View style={{zIndex: 2}}><Text>HERE example view</Text></View>}
      ...
      />
   </View>
  <View style={{ 
       position: "absolute", 
       zIndex: 1,
       alignContent: "center",
       alignItems: "center",
       alignSelf: "center"
     }}>
     <Text>HERE What you need too hide</Text>
  </View>
```